# How to set jQuery Cookie for slideDown menu?

Tags: jquery, cookies, slidedown, jquery-cookie

I have a slideDown menu and I want to remember the last state of the menu so that on page load the last state is already selected. I am trying to accomplish this by using [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and this is what i did:

```
$("#menu h3").click(function(){
    $("#menu ul ul").slideUp();
    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');   
        $.cookie(id, $(this).is(':visible') ? "closed" : "open");
        if ($.cookie(id) == "open") {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    }
});
```

[**>> jsFiddle <<**](http://jsfiddle.net/K4pUV/)
When I reload the page I don't get the last state and `.slideDown()` doesn't work. 
Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a little. Try this:

```
var active = $.cookie('active'),
    $h3 = $("#menu h3"),
    $activeH3 = $h3.filter('#' + active);

$h3.click(function(e, speed) {
    $("#menu ul ul").slideUp(speed);
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown(speed);
        $.cookie('active', this.id);
    }
});

if ($activeH3.next().is(':hidden')) {
    $activeH3.trigger('click', [0]);
}
```

Make sure you also set ids for your `h3` elements.

#### Demo http://jsfiddle.net/K4pUV/1/